# RAID 1 mirror on Ubtunu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, backup, raid

I have about 650GB of data files on a 1T Toshiba hard drive.

This drive used to be in a RAID 1 mirror with Intel Rapid Storage Technology.

Planning to convert this drive back into a non-RAID drive and mount it in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Backup plan would be to use Duplicati to sync this drive to an external USB drive and cloud storage (probably Google Drive)

I have a CyberPower UPS that works on Ubuntu so I’m not really concerned with power outages and weird cache situations.

Still considering setting up another RAID 1 mirror.

All of my previous data loss came from failed physical drives.

What are some recommendations for implementing a RAID 1 mirror on Ubuntu?

RAID card/memory/battery seems like overkill for just 2 drives/650GB and sounds pricey.

But I keep reading that software/fake RAID is just a bad idea.

I was researching mdadm/webmin but then I saw this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAuEgepZG_8

and I realize I need to get a FreeNas box going eventually.

Comment: RAID is not backup. Linux mdadm software RAID1 is a very good idea! (Its not fake RAID and many experts - including myself - believe it is sometimes better then hardware RAID as you don't need to worry about RAID card failure.

Comment: "RAID is not backup" - Good point. I reformatted the question to keep backup and RAID separate.

Answer (score 1):

Backup is not only a way to secure your datas from an external disaster, but also a way to prevent from human errors.

If you want your system to be 24×7 available, RAID is the good answer.
If you want it to store datas modified by humans, and be able to rollback a change, you’d better use the secondary disk in an external device, and "regularly" store the changes on them.

RAID 1 or 5 (or 6) is just a technical answer to 99.7% availability.

Comment: I’m seeing that the initial question has significantly changed since my answer.
In fact, it has so change, that I can no more understand wha exactly is your concern?
How do you want us to help you? What is your question?

Comment: My apologies. I must not have notifications turned on. Ultimately, my question is (was): "What are some recommendations for implementing a RAID 1 mirror on Ubuntu?" Initially, I set up Intel RST again and used it with Webmin to manage the RAID 1 mirror, but that led to file corruption.  I ended up just turning Intel RST off and building a RAD 1 mirror with Webmin directly